# How to assign multiple onError functions to a promise (returned by angular's $http.post)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

My AngularJS code needs to chain multiple `onSuccess`, `onError` functions to a promise returned by `$http.post`

```
  var promise = $http.post(url);
     promise
      .then(
          /*success 1*/function () { console.log("success 1"); },
          /*error 1*/function () { console.log("error 1"); })
      .then(
          /*success 2*/function () { console.log("success 2"); },
          /*error 2*/function () { console.log("error 2"); });
```

The problem with above code is that it prints `error 1` > `success 2` when the HTTP response fails instead of `error 1` > `error 2`.

I did some research on stackoverflow and found that when you have access to `$q` you can just do `$q.reject()` in `error 1` to trigger `error 2` but in my case i only have access to the promise returned by `$http.post`. So what do I do?

**P.S.** Of course, I can call `error2()` from inside of `error 1` but i want to chain them because it looks more readable and extensible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a value (or returning no value) from a success/error handler will resolve the promise for the next then block in the chain. To propagate the rejection, return $q.reject():

```
var promise = $http.post(url);
 promise
  .then(
      /*success 1*/function () { console.log("success 1"); },
      /*error 1*/function () { console.log("error 1"); return $q.reject();})
  .then(
      /*success 2*/function () { console.log("success 2"); },
      /*error 2*/function () { console.log("error 2"); });
```

Comment: thanks! it worked perfectly. Can you please tell me one more thing.. why can't I use return `$q.resolve()` similarly in the success functions? Because when I do I get this error: `$q.resolve is not a function`

Comment: pixelbits, this is an incorrect approach - see why in my answer. @supersan, by returning `$q.reject` you are effectively re-throwing a rejection, which I don't believe is what you are after

Comment: What's wrong with re-throwing a rejection? In code, when you catch an exception, it's considered resolved, and the calling code can continue. When you catch an exception and re-throw, you're handling the error and re throwing it so that the calling code can do the same. Perfectly valid scenario

Comment: @supersan returning a value from a success/error handler will resolve the promise for the next then block in the chain. However, to answer your question, you can alternatively use $q.when() to resolve. This post might be helpful:http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2735-q-when-is-the-missing-q-resolve-method-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: There is nothing wrong with rethrowing - if this is the intent. My point was that I don't think this *was* the intent - since the OP wanted `error 1 > error 2` after HTTP failure. My second point was that it leaves `success2` without a "catch".

Comment: I'm not sure who's right, I'll leave it up to the OP. But exception-usage rules apply here the same way; if the first-level can't do anything meaningful to discover the reason for the exception, then just let the exception go to the next method up. Similarly, you can basically take out the /*error 1*/ line, and the error 1 object will appear in the /*error 2*/ function on a failure.

Comment: To me, I thought the question was clear and his reasons for extensibility was valid.  The intent of the code appears to be for illustrative purposes and demonstrated in a clear and concise manner.

Comment: What is "extensibility" in your understanding? And what were "his reasons" for it? The OP question is an example of misunderstanding of promise chaining, that I am afraid, your answer, perpetuated. And you still haven't addressed my second point on success2 without a "catch". (That's not to say that the OP's question itself was bad - it is a good question)

Comment: He stated extensibility:P  I don't see how the OP has misunderstood promise chaining. Rather than assume that, just answer the question

Comment: @New Dev The OP asked a question, you made an assumption (unverified), and then built an entire answer around the assumption. Are you sure you're not perpetuating the wrong point here?

Comment: @pixelbits, this has gone for too long.. so, this is my last point. This approach is based on some notion of "extensibility". Without it, Cerbrus's answer is the simplest way to address what OP wanted, namely `error1 > error2` in response to an HTTP failure. The OP was surprised why it was not happening for the (most likely) incorrect way he approached it. And your answer "patched" his approach, whereas you had an opportunity to question why he did it, and to suggest a proper way to think about. And again, you still haven't addressed my second point

Comment: @New Dev Your answer is based on assumptions that I don't care to address... That includes your second point.  A "patch"? Are you serious? The only assumption that I have made is that the OP has legitimate reasons for propagating errors and that the question is valid. Why exactly are you assuming the opposite without asking first:P

Answer (score 1):

Your question stems from some misunderstanding of what promises enable - namely, async code composition that parallels that of a synchronous code with `try`/`catch`, with proper exception handling.

I am specifically referring to your statement:

> "but i want to chain them because it looks more readable and extensible."

as the source of misunderstanding of chaining.

If your example was synchronous (assuming all async calls were blocking), this is likely what you would have wanted to do:

```
try {
  var data = $http.post(url); // blocking
  var res1 = doSuccess1(data);
  var ret = doSuccess2(res1);
}
catch(e){
  errorHandler1(e);
  errorHandler2(e);
}
```

And not this:

```
try {
  try {
    var data = $http.post(url);
    var res1 = doSuccess1(data);
  } catch (e) {
    errorHandler1(e);
    // throw ""; // this is what returning $q.reject would have done - a rethrow
  }
} catch (e) {
    errorHandler2(e);
}
var ret = doSuccess2(res1);
```

which is what you would have achieved with your chaining. In other words, nested `try`/`catch` and unhandled exception in `doSuccess2`.

The following is the async parallel of the first approach:

```
var ret;
$http.post(url)
  .then(function(data){
     var res1 = doSuccess1(data);
     ret = doSuccess2(res1);
  }
  .catch(function(e){ // or .then(null, handler)
     doError1(e);
     doError2(e);
  })
```

And if one of `doSuccessN` functions were also async:

```
var ret;
$http.post(url)
  .then(doSuccess1Async)
  .then(function(res1){
     ret = doSuccess2(res1);
  }
  .catch(function(e){ // or .then(null, handler)
     doError1(e);
     doError2(e);
  })
```

Comment: I think you are suggesting that having one top-level rejection handler is the proper and only way to handle rejections. This is misleading. In the context of a single promise, it is certainly a valid approach to want to handle the error in an appropriate way that makes sense for that promise, and propagate the rejection if it is chained.

Comment: At no point did I suggest that this is "the proper and only way". I explicitly stated that if top-level try/catch was the intent, then this is the parallel approach with promises

Comment: Ok, I've understood.. the `try {  try {` example really helped me to understand what i'm actually doing when returning `$q.reject()` (I didn't earlier). Thanks so much for explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the handlers in a function, in the success / error handler parameters:

```
var promise = $http.post(url);
promise
  .then(function(argX, argY){
      success1(argX, argY);
      success2(argX, argY);
  },
  function(argX, argY){
      error1(argX, argY);
      error2(argX, argY);
  });
```

Comment: This wouldn't catch exceptions in `success1` and `success2`, but it seems that the OP either didn't want or hadn't considered doing. But for the sake of good practices,  it's always better to complete the chain with a `.catch` (or the equivalent final `.then(null, handler)`

Comment: Actually, I am fairly certain, that there is no `argY` in a resolved promise. Promise only has a single resolved value.

Comment: Those arguments are just intended as an example.

Comment: No, I'm saying that `argY` is always `undefined` when you do `.then(function (argX, argY){...})`

Comment: @NewDev: I've _only_ added those arguments to show that you should pass arguments _like that_. Those are in no way meant to accurately represent the arguments passed to the callback. Otherwise, I'd have given them sensible names.

Comment: You are not understanding my point. You cannot `resolve(x, y)` - in general. `resolve` accepts only 1 parameter: http://plnkr.co/edit/5p1xVeVvqUe3N2qrNNn7?p=preview

Comment: You're missing my point: It _doesn't matter_ what kind of parameters `resolve` accepts. Those arguments are _only_ meant to illustrate the fact that you can / have to pass any provided parameter(s) through.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73439/discussion-between-new-dev-and-cerbrus).